# Updating a UITableView's data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my application, I have a UITableView with a few rows (let's call it TV1), now, at the bottom of these rows is a row that drills down into another (TV2). This new TV2 asks you which type of data you would like to add to the first view. Then, when the user selects which kind, they're brought to another view, in which they fill in some fields, the data is saved, and they're sent back to TV1, however, the data they entered, isn't loaded and I'm not really sure how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you did this already, but how about using `[TV1 reloadData];`? This forces the entire table to reload, yet there are also more specific methods for reloading just the cells that have been altered. See also the documentation: [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4)

Answer (score 1):

Reload your table view by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the viewcontroller's `viewWillAppear:` method. It will be called when the user switches back to your view. Right before it is actually put on screen.